# Is it good to create the session factory in each micro-services

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot

I have 3 micro-services which are running on different ports.I am using spring boot, Hibernate and nginx. So i want to do the database operation (CURD) inside the each micro-services.So should i create session-factory inside each micro-services or create a separate micro-service which will be providing the session-factory to each micro-services on demand.

Answer (score 1):

A SessionFactory is always an object which lives within one JVM. So if you have multiple JVM processes with different applications, each of those has to have it's own SessionFactory object. There are certainly ways to share such functionality, but it is definitely not recommended in a microservice architecture.

Comment: My answer still applies. Each application keeps its own SessionFactory (if the application has persistence. If not, then you don't need it obviously). You should also keep the databases (or at least schemas) separated for each application, which already presumes that you have different persistence configurations per application).

Comment: I have Same DB for all the micro services and all the tables inside that. So Some of tables will be using by first micro-services and remaining for second and third micro services.

Comment: That is an indicator for a bad design. I suggest to revise if you really need microservices or if it wouldn't be better to have the functionalities in one application. Especially if you also cannot deploy them separately.

Comment: Suppose i have two micro services(Teacher and students) both have there own DB. But we know there is relationship between teacher and student so how we will perform the CRUD operation. Because we don't have the student and teacher in single micro-services

Comment: Simply how will we perform JOIN in micro-service architecture

Comment: You simply don't. If it's necessary, then again it's an indicator that the way how you have designed your microservices is probably to fine grained.

Comment: Can you please help me into this JOIN problem?

Comment: Then please create a new question with a detailed description of your problem

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you shouldn't allow multiple micro-services access the database.
Instead, create a micro-service, say, `db-handler`, which will have all the Hibernate code and DAOs. Other micro-services can call `db-handler` to perform various operations via REST calls.

This way you won't have to configure Hibernate in multiple micro-services. And in case you need to change some configuration or upgrade Hibernate version, or do any changes related to database, it's all at one place, so it will be easier to maintain. And of course there will only be a single `SessionFactory`, residing in `db-handler`.

Comment: Maybe you are correct but according to me we are not following the micro-service architecture. in this case each and every micro-service will interact with this common db-handler to perform the DB operation.